# How to get youku video id from url by regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youku

I need to get youku video id from url by regex, for example:

```
http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTg3OTc3MzY4.html
```

I only need `XNTg3OTc3MzY4` to keep in a variable.

How can I write it in function below

```
var youkuEmbed = "[[*supplier-video]]";

var youkuUrl = youkuEmbed.match(/http://v\.youku\.com/v_show/id_(\w+)\.html/);
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: `'http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTg3OTc3MzY4.html'.match(/[^.\/_]+(?=\.\w+$)/g);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
id_(\w+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xJ7uM1/1)**

[image]

The idea is to match the `_id` and the capture all the alphanumeric strings.

```
MATCH 1
1.  [29-42] `XNTg3OTc3MzY4`
```

If you go the Code Generator section you can get the code. However, you can use something like this:

```
var myString = 'http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTg3OTc3MzY4.html';
var myRegexp = /id_(\w+)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  
//Shows: XNTg3OTc3MzY4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
http://v\.youku\.com/v_show/id_(\w+)\.html
```

Your match is in the first capturing group.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/yU4mW1/1).

Answer (score 1):

Id the id always follows `id_`, you could possibly split the string.

```
'http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTg3OTc3MzY4.html'.split(/.*id_|\./)[1]
//=> 'XNTg3OTc3MzY4'
```

For this specific string, you could just do.

```
'http://youku.com/id_XNTg30Tc3MzY4.html'.split(/id_|\./)[2]
//=> 'XNTg3OTc3MzY4'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to escape all the slashes because that's the delimiter for the regex itself:

`var youkuUrl = youkuEmbed.match(/http:\/\/v\.youku\.com\/v_show\/id_(\w+)\.html/);`

Then use the first capture group, as Unihedron stated.